# Parsing json string for multiple stock quotes

Tags: json

This is the data returned from a request for "JNJ" and "ADP" stock information.

```
var quote = new Object(); 
    quote['JNJ'] = {
    Ticker: 'JNJ', 
    Valoren: 943981, 
    ExchangeCode: 321, 
    Exchange: 'NY', 
    ExchangeName: 'New York Stock Exchange', 
    ExchangeShortName: 'NYSE', 
    TradeTime: 1375906505,
    Volume: 9052146, 
    Last: 93.66, 
    Open: 93.60, 
    High: 94.03, 
    Low: 93.47,
    PrevClose: 93.81, 
    Change: -0.15, 
    ChangePercent: -0.1599, 
    Bid: 93.66,
    Ask: 93.68, 
    BidSize: 2500, 
    AskSize: 800, 
    Name: 'Johnson & Johnson',
    ShortName: 'Johnson', 
    ISIN: 'US4781601046', 
    SharesOutstanding: 2818073863
}; 
quote['ADP'] = {
    Ticker: 'ADP', 
    Valoren: 910042,
    ExchangeCode: 537, 
    Exchange: 'NQ', 
    ExchangeName: 'Nasdaq Stock Market', 
    ExchangeShortName: 'Nasdaq', 
    TradeTime: 1375905600, 
    Volume: 1460941, 
    Last: 71.99, 
    Open: 72.11, 
    High: 72.28, 
    Low: 71.67, 
    PrevClose: 72.24, 
    Change: -0.25, 
    ChangePercent: -0.3461, 
    Bid: 71.99, 
    Ask: 72.00, 
    BidSize: 9300, 
    AskSize: 300, 
    Name: 'Automatic Data Processing',
    ShortName: 'Automatic Data', 
    ISIN: 'US0530151036', 
    SharesOutstanding: 485222417
}; 
eval('updateQuotes(quote)');
```

I am a novice at this. I have tried json.net but I continue to get errors. It appears not to be proper json. I thought maybe stripping of everything before the "{" and after the "}" may work, but so far no luck. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
By limiting it to a single stock, then stripping off everything before the "{" and after the "}", i can parse it just fine using:

```
string input = json;
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, string> sData = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
string _Ticker = sData["Ticker"].ToString();
string _Last = sData["Last"].ToString();
Console.WriteLine(_Ticker + "  " + _Last);
```

Comment: If JSON.Net threw a parsing exception, I suspect it isn't well-formed JSON.

Comment: poppyc, can you read your question?

Comment: This is definitely not well-formed JSON. I think it is actually javascript code. Are you sure you are requesting this correctly?

Comment: The formatting definitely helps!  Can you see that your text includes two separate 'hunks' of JSON data?  Can you show us how you are going about executing the WebService call to get this output?  I think you may be dealing with some peculiarity in the API you are calling, in terms of asking for multiple quotes in one call.

Comment: What language are you working with, and what parser???  (The above appears to be the result of parsing valid JSON into objects of some language, but I don't recognize which one.)  The outermost JSON entity (here named "quote") is presumably an "object", with keys "JNJ", "ADP", et al, and corresponding values that are "maps" (JSON "objects").

Comment: That's not json, the quotes should be double quotes, field names should be in dquotes. Values that aren't integers or True or False should be in dquotes. It's all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the last *eval('updateQuotes(quote)')* Also check the object that you are deserializing to is of this format

```
public class RootObject
{

public string Ticker { get; set; }
public int Valoren { get; set; }
public int ExchangeCode { get; set; }
public string Exchange { get; set; }
public string ExchangeName { get; set; }
public string ExchangeShortName { get; set; }
public int TradeTime { get; set; }
public int Volume { get; set; }
public double Last { get; set; }
public double Open { get; set; }
public double High { get; set; }
public double Low { get; set; }
public double PrevClose { get; set; }
public double Change { get; set; }
public double ChangePercent { get; set; }
public double Bid { get; set; }
public double Ask { get; set; }
public int BidSize { get; set; }
public int AskSize { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string ShortName { get; set; }
public string ISIN { get; set; }
public int SharesOutstanding { get; set; }
}
```

You can verify any json string to C# object using this http://json2csharp.com/